# unable to get default constructor while using Unity

Tags: c#, integration-testing

### Problem

I am trying to test my service. when I run test it show this error and test failed. my unity config class is in my asp.net mvc  project and my test is in different project I don't know where I  am doing wrong.

> unable to get default constructor for Class servicetest

### ServiceTest

```
 [TestClass]
public class ImportServiceTests 
{
    private readonly IImportService _importService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public ImportServiceTests(IImportService importService, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _importService = importService;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ImportCategories()
    {
        string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"E:\categories.xlsx");
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Stream data = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

            _importService.ImportCategoriesFromXlsx(data);
        }
    }
}
```

### UnityConfig

```
    public class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the configured Unity container.
    /// </summary>
    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.</summary>
    /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
    /// <remarks>There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or API controllers (unless you want to 
    /// change the defaults), as Unity allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously registered.</remarks>
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
        // container.LoadConfiguration();

        // TODO: Register your types here
        // container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IImportService, ImportService>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IDataContext, PriceHunterDataContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use Dependancy injection like that in unit tests. Your composition root doesn't run when running tests. You will need to mock IImportService and IUnitOfWork in a method decorated with [TestInitialize] (call this method TestSetup or something) and remove your constructor.

Comment: @garethb I am trying to create integration testing so what I can do in set method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263197/mvc-integration-tests-with-unity-ioc